# Check correlation between labels in two set of non-binary categorical labels?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, multilevel-analysis, cross-correlation

I have a dataset with ~6k data points. Each data point has two labels, both categorical (unlike measuring temperature from cold, warm, to hot, my labels in the same category is totally non-continuous).

Category A contains labels ABCD... in total >10 labels.
Category a contains labels abcd... in total 30 labels.

I would like to find out, if one data point belongs to category e, is it more likely to belong to category B? (This is an example, I would like to find out the answer for every pair of labels which in total is like ~400 pairs of correlation)

Based on a general inspection, I'm pretty sure a lot of these labels are unrelated (but a few seems related, I inspected the data by drawing a scatter plot with each category as an axis), however, given that some category contains more data points and some less, I haven't yet find a valid way of spotting those pairs with significant correlation.

Thank you!

(Or should I just perform 400 chi-square tests...)

Comment: If these are categorical then correlation coefficients are out. Frequency tables are a good start.

Comment: I have deleted my answer until I get resolution to the issue described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605746/is-multinomial-logistic-regression-symmetric).