# Is multinomial logistic regression symmetric?

Tags: regression, r-squared, multinomial-logit, symmetry

Simple linear regression is symmetric in the sense that, if I regress $Y$ on $X$ or $X$ on $Y$, I get the same $R^2$ and result from the overall $F$-test.

```
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
x <- rnorm(N)
y <- rnorm(N)
Ly <- lm(y ~ x)
Lx <- lm(x ~ y)
summary(Ly)
summary(Lx)

################################################################################
#
# OUTPUT
#
################################################################################

> summary(Ly)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5268 -0.6544 -0.0301  0.6608  3.1812 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.0146774  0.0308043   0.476    0.634
x           0.0004153  0.0305085   0.014    0.989

Residual standard error: 0.9738 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  1.857e-07, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.001002 
F-statistic: 0.0001853 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: 0.9891

> summary(Lx)

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ y)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.2220 -0.7032 -0.0229  0.6861  4.5979 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.0239849  0.0319559  -0.751    0.453
y            0.0004471  0.0328434   0.014    0.989

Residual standard error: 1.01 on 998 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  1.857e-07, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.001002 
F-statistic: 0.0001853 on 1 and 998 DF,  p-value: 0.9891
```

Assuming two categorical variables, $X$ and $Y$, I can fit a multinomial logistic regression using either as the feature to predict the other. I can also calculate $R^2_{McFadden}$ for each model and overall likelihood ratio tests. In a simulation, it seems to matter which variable is the feature. However, I wonder if this is just a numerical issue. Does the math say these are the same?

```
library(nnet)
library(lmtest)

# Simulate data
#
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
y <- as.factor(sample(seq(1, 30, 1), N, replace = T))
x <- as.factor(sample(seq(1, 10, 1), N, replace = T))

# Fit the model 
# 
L1 <- nnet::multinom(y ~ x)

# Intercept-only model 
# 
L0 <- nnet::multinom(y ~ 1)

MNLL1 <- L1$value
MNLL0 <- L0$value

R2_McFadden <- 1 - MNLL1/MNLL0
R2_McFadden

# G-test (“lr” means likelihood ratio)
#
lmtest::lrtest(L1, L0)

################################################################################
#
# OUTPUT
#
################################################################################

> R2_McFadden
[1] 0.03431655
> 
> # G-test (“lr” means likelihood ratio)
> #
> lmtest::lrtest(L1, L0)
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: y ~ x
Model 2: y ~ 1
  #Df  LogLik   Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1 290 -3267.9                       
2  29 -3384.1 -261 232.26     0.8994
```

However, when I flip the variables, the numbers change slightly.

```
L2 <- nnet::multinom(x ~ y)
L3 <- nnet::multinom(x ~ 1)
MNLL2 <- L2$value
MNLL3 <- L3$value

R2_McFadden <- 1 - MNLL2/MNLL3
R2_McFadden

lmtest::lrtest(L2, L3) 

################################################################################
#
# OUTPUT
#
################################################################################

> R2_McFadden
[1] 0.05055947
> 
> lmtest::lrtest(L2, L3) 
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: x ~ y
Model 2: x ~ 1
  #Df  LogLik   Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1 270 -2180.7                       
2   9 -2296.8 -261 232.26     0.8994
```

**EDIT**

I thought both the $R^2_{McFadden}$ and the p-value differed, but it's only $R^2_{McFadden}$. That strikes me as the weirdest possibility of them all: a change to the value that quantifies relationship strength ($R^2_{McFadden}$) yet no change to the p-value testing that relationship.